# No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload .Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, stripe-payments, aws-api-gateway, webhooks

I have a stripe webhook endponit that call a AWS Lambda through  API gateway. In this function I need to verify  and verify the signature of the event. Here is the code :

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({ region: "us-east-1" });
let stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_#####');

exports.handler = async (req) => {
    console.log('hit')
    let event;
    let response;
    try {
        event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
            req.body,
            req.headers['Stripe-Signature'],
            process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET
        );
        console.log(event)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(`⚠️  Webhook signature verification failed.`);
        console.log(
            `⚠️  Check the env file and enter the correct webhook secret.`
        );
        response = {
            statusCode: 400,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "access-control-allow-origin": "*"
            },
        };
        return response
    }
    // Extract the object from the event.
    const dataObject = event.data.object;
    // Handle the event
    // Review important events for Billing webhooks
    // https://stripe.com/docs/billing/webhooks
    // Remove comment to see the various objects sent for this sample
    switch (event.type) {
        case 'invoice.paid':
            // Used to provision services after the trial has ended.
            // The status of the invoice will show up as paid. Store the status in your
            // database to reference when a user accesses your service to avoid hitting rate limits.
            break;
        case 'invoice.payment_failed':
            // If the payment fails or the customer does not have a valid payment method,
            //  an invoice.payment_failed event is sent, the subscription becomes past_due.
            // Use this webhook to notify your user that their payment has
            // failed and to retrieve new card details.
            break;
        case 'customer.subscription.deleted':
            if (event.request != null) {
                // handle a subscription cancelled by your request
                // from above.
            } else {
                // handle subscription cancelled automatically based
                // upon your subscription settings.
            }
            break;
        default:
        // Unexpected event type
    }

    response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "access-control-allow-origin": "*"
        },
    };
    return response;

};
```

But I get this error : StripeSignatureVerificationError: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is make sure the `STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET` is properly defined in your Lambda environment variables configuration

[image]

Contrary to what people may think, the value for `STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET` is the one marked in the following image with the name `Signing secret`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

So the issue here is `req.headers['Stripe-Signature']` that you are passing to the

```
stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
  req.body,
  req.headers['Stripe-Signature'],
  process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET
)
```

will be `undefined`

So you need to configure the custom header configuration in API gateway as described in this document [to configure custom header through API Gateway to a Lambda function using custom Lambda integration](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/custom-headers-api-gateway-lambda/)

Once this configuration is done you will see the values as below in `req` object

```
{
    "body": {
    // Stripe body content goes here
    },
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "*/*; q=0.5, application/xml",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Host": "udpou*****",
        "Stripe-Signature": "t=*,v1=*,v0=*",
        "User-Agent": "Stripe/1.0 (+https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks)",
        "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "*",
        "X-Forwarded-For": "*",
        "X-Forwarded-Port": "443",
        "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https"
    }
}
```

Now you can access `'Stripe-Signature'` in the headers and pass it to `stripe.webhooks.constructEvent()` method.

Let me know in the comment if this works.